# Two Dynamic SCNNodes Not Colliding (Scenekit)

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, arkit, scnnode

I am currently in the process of making a Scenekit game in ARKit.

I have two dynamic SCNNodes, and when they make contact with each other, they pass through one another.

I have set up each node's physics body's collisionBitMask to include one another, like so:

```
ballNode.physicsBody?.collisionBitMask = BodyType.floor.rawValue |  BodyType.opponent.rawValue
```

I have also set up the physics body of each node to be dynamic, so that the node is affected by forces and collisions.

When I call `physicsWorld(_ world: SCNPhysicsWorld, didBegin contact: SCNPhysicsContact)` it does correctly register that there is a collision between the two nodes, however the nodes continue to pass through one another.

When I make one of the nodes kinematic, instead of dynamic, it correctly blocks the other node, and they do not pass through one another. But when it is kinematic, it does not respond to the force I apply to it, so I want to keep it dynamic.

Is it possible to have two dynamic nodes to collide with one another without passing through?

Answer (score 0):

I think the "physicsShape" is missing, so declared as "nil"

```
geometryNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape: nil)
```

Instead:

```
let pShape = SCNPhysicsShape(geometry: SCNBox(width: 0.1, height: 0.1, length: 0.1, chamferRadius: 0.0), options: [:])
boxNode.physicsBody = SCNPhysicsBody(type: .Dynamic, shape: pShape)
```

I hope the helps, please post the code.

An alternative for the shape creation is  [init(node:options:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsshape/1508889-init)

Comment: If the shape is declared as `nil` then SceneKit will automatically determine the best shape for the physics body.

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnphysicsbody/1514797-init